# Webcomic starring a pair of cats who move into a haunted mansion - R.O.B. the robot and spirits

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

So I know that I read this webcomic about two years ago. The two main characters are two anthropomorphic cats. I don't think they're directly related, or romantically attached. There are a lot of videogame references, including that the mansion they're living in has a spirit of death who likes to play video-games (only one of the two cats can see him) who is occasionally held at bay by [R.O.B.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.O.B.) the Robot with a Zapper in his hands. At least one of the cats was something like a Siamese or one of the Egyptian breeds with a small head and comparatively large ears. I think they were an orange color.

I think that it's within the last few years that the webcomic was released, although most of the references were to old NES games.

It is not [VG Cats](https://www.vgcats.com/), [Housepets!](https://www.housepetscomic.com/), or [theGaMERCat](https://www.thegamercat.com/) just to rule out a few that I ran into while browsing around. The cats are full anthro, standing upright and using hands. I don't remember if humans exist at all, but I'm pretty sure that there were other upright animals. I want to say that one of them renamed the house (which they'd inherited) as "Hyrule Mansion" or something similar.

Comment: It's not http://vgcats.com ?

Comment: @Adeptus: No. It's also not *Housepets!* which also has anthro-cats and video games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm an idiot. [*Savestate*](https://www.savestatecomic.com/). I was fixated on the idea of them being cats, so I just kind of stepped right past it, because it's about a pair of **dogs**. And they [renamed "Family Estate" to "Sav Estate"](https://www.savestatecomic.com/2014/07/savestate/) with a TriForce above it.

[image: Comic showing renaming]

[R.O.B. holding the spirit at bay](https://www.savestatecomic.com/2014/11/light-gun/)

[image: Comic showing spirit held at bay]